# How to specify a wrapper class in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have set up a standard Maps Activity in Android Studio. I then need to add a 'wrapper' class so that I can implement a class that is different from the MapsActivity's OnMapReadyCallback. This wrapper class has no visual components and should not create a View and simply then calls MapsActivity to create the map view.

Everything compiles, but when run no view appears.

If I move the quit looper from dispose to MReady just after map is created I only get the following line in the log.

> E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a
>   callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=10, legacyType=-1, [
>   Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]

But still no view appears. Below code updated to latest. Also none of my Log.d/i messages appear in the log although it's set to verbose.

Code -
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.booxotel.smallgminterface">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name = ".SmallMap">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.booxotel.smallgminterface.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

SmallMap.java (part of)

```
public class SmallMap extends Application implements FREExtension {
    public static final String TAG = "MapInterface";
    private static GoogleMap gMap;
    private static LatLng cmap;
    private static MarksData md;
    private Handler mHandler;

    public static FREContext extensionContext;
    public static Context appContext;
    public static SettingsContentObserver mSettingsWatcher;

    public ShowMap shm;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        appContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public class ShowMap extends Thread {
        ShowMap() {
            prepareThread(false);
        }

        public void prepareThread(Boolean quit){
            Log.i(TAG, "prepare thread");
            if (gMap == null && !quit) {
                Looper.prepare();
                mHandler = new Handler();
                Intent intent = new Intent(SmallMap.appContext, MapsActivity.class);
                appContext.startActivity(intent);
            }else if(quit) {
                Looper.myLooper().quit();
            }
            Looper.loop();
        }
    }

    public class MReady implements MapReadyEvent {
        @Override
        public void MapReady() {
            gMap = MapsActivity.getMap();
            shm.prepareThread(true);
            Log.i(TAG, "map ready");
            extensionContext.dispatchStatusEventAsync("mapReady", "true");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public FREContext createContext(String contextType) {
        shm = new ShowMap();
        shm.prepareThread(false);
        return new MapInterfaceContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Extension disposed.");
        Context context = appContext.getApplicationContext();
        context.getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(mSettingsWatcher);
        appContext = null;
        extensionContext = null;
        mSettingsWatcher = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Extension initialized.");
    }
}
```

MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public static GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        MapReadyEvent mre = new MapReadyEvent() {
            @Override
            public void MapReady() {}
        };
        mre.MapReady();
    }

    public static GoogleMap getMap() {
        return mMap;
    }
}
```

MapReadyEvent.java

```
public interface MapReadyEvent {
    void MapReady();
}
```

activity_maps.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="311dp"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="710dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
        tools:context="com.mysite.testmap.MapsActivity" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Found some errors myself and now map still doesn't appear but tests complete and logcat contains only one line : Failed to connect to server: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "play.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname

Comment: I'm not sure which parts of the code I should post to help. The wrapper or some of the xml files?

Comment: Most common reason for "Unable to resolve host" is the missing internet permission, did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` to your `AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: OK now it runs with no errors or warnings but still no view appears. I will try to sort out the relevant code and post it.

Comment: I assume that you have created the Google API key correctly (see [step 4](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start))?

Comment: The fragment has a very large `layout_marginLeft`. What happens when you remove the margins and set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` on `match_parent`?

Comment: The google API key is correct. The layout is designed for a tablet. It still does nothing even if the fragment uses match_parent.

Comment: I see that the `SmallMap` class is a child of the `Application` class, but the application class is not added in you `AndroidManifest.xml`, so it is never called. Add `android:name=".SmallMap"` to the `application` tag in you `AndroidManifest.xml`. Are you sure there are no errors/warnings in your log? Are you testing on an Emulator?

Comment: After this change to AndroidManifest, I now get this in the log :

Comment: You forgot to paste your log ;-)

Comment: Couldn't paste here - too long it says - so it's at end of original question after the code above.

Comment: If I move the quit looper from dispose to MReady just after map is created I only get the following line in the log.

E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=10, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]

But still no view appears. Above code updated to latest. Also none of my Log.d/i messages appear in the log although it's set to verbose.

Comment: I will try to look at it this week. I'll suggest you for now to focus on displaying the map in a simple example.

Comment: I started from where I had a simple map displayed then added the wrapper. I'm now trying creating a basic project and then adding a map from that start point.

Answer (score 0):

The `startActivity` is not called from the main thread.

Use this instead:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    .post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SmallMap.appContext, MapsActivity.class);
         appContext.startActivity(intent);
     }
   });
```